# is performUpdatesAnimated in IGListkit always necessary when data changes?

Tags: ios

I've been implementing IGListKit on my current project but I read that

> IGListKit automatically diffs your objects and performs animated batch updates on the UICollectionView for whatever changed.

However, I set the collectionView array but whenever it changes, the collectionView is not automatically updated unless I call `performUpdatesAnimated`

Am I missing something? because the idea I got was that IGListKit automatically performed all the updates for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"IGListKit automatically diffs your objects" means that `IGListKit` elaborates insert/updates/delete/move for you, but you still have to manually call `performUpdatesAnimated` when you want to update your `collectionView`

Answer (score -1):

YES, the offical document says that "Never call -performBatchUpdates or -reloadData again", those mothods belong to instance of UICollectionView, and IGListKit has offered some better performance methods base on "Diff algorithm", it will refresh the UI that need to refresh.

Comment: Thank you for answering a question on Stack Overflow. However, how is your answer relevant to the question of the OP? The OP expects updates to happen automatically and they don't. Your answer doesn't explain that in any way.